# Create TypeORM query to retrieve all object from one table and add column based on indication from other table (Node/NestJS)

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

**I'm using TypeORM query builder for my backend and I have an issue i will appreciate your help with.**
I have three data base tables - *USERS*, *ITEMS* & *USER_FAVORITES_ITEMS* (relation table).
each USER have MANY favorites items and each item can be *FAVORITE* to many USERS (*Many To Many* relation).

Now, the result I'm looking for is to create query that will return all items on the database with extra column called *IS_FAV* (boolean) -> *if the item appears in the USER_FAVORITES_ITEMS for this user I want it to be TRUE, else it should be FALSE.*

[image]

This is how my MANY To Many table looks like (very simple).

Comment: Can you pls. show the expected structure of the result set? And `users` is the same as `tourists`, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use this:

```
 let query = this.userRepository
      .createQueryBuilder('ITEMS')
      .leftJoin('ITEMS.USERS', 'USERS')
      .select('ITEMS')
      .addSelect('ITEMS.USERS)', 'USER_FAVORITES_ITEMS');
    const inputs = await query.getRawMany();
inputs.map((item)=>{
if(item.USERS){
return {
...item,
USER_FAVORITES_ITEMS: true,
}
} else {
return {
...item,
USER_FAVORITES_ITEMS: true,
}
}
});
```

you may change the code to what you want, but you can use this way.

Comment: Hi, thank a lot.
I was able to achieve the required result using the 'getRawMany' - BUT I wonder if there is a good way to keep the entity structure (which means not using getRawMany OR something else I didn't think about). any idea ?

Comment: i searched for some feature like this, but i was unable, only raw many work, structure is a bit disrupt, if yoy log the result can find how to extract data. let me write a piece of code about how to extract data

Answer (score 0):

this is how to derive values from getRawMany():

```
export default class **** {
  constructor(data: any) {
    const product: Product = {
      createdById: data.product_createdById,
      updatedById: data.product_updatedById,
      productCategory: {
        createdById: data.category_createdById,
        updatedById: data.category_updatedById,
      },
    };
  ********
}
```